# WKWebView history serialization on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to restore `WKWebView` navigation after app will restarts. I can inherit from base web view and take more control with it.

```swift
class WebViewHistory: WKBackForwardList {
// additional control with history items
// can perform custom init
}

class WebView: WKWebView {

    var history: WebViewHistory

    override var backForwardList: WebViewHistory {
        return history
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, history: WebViewHistory) {
        self.history = history
        super.init(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

For serialization I need serialize at least one `WKBackForwardListItem`. So here I face up with troubles.

```swift
class WebNavigationItem: WKBackForwardListItem {}

// but I cant create this objects
let item1 = WKBackForwardListItem() // 'init()' is unavailable
let item2 = WebNavigationItem() // 'WebNavigationItem' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
```

How to serialize history of `WKWebView`?

---

So for now I see only 1 option: make custom navigation with serialization support and forgot about `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures`. And it required more code for implementing all logic of default web view history.

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting iOS 15 or above, you should look into [`WKWebView.interactionState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3752236-interactionstate).

It's erased to `Any?` but appears to be a plain old `[NS]Data` value [behind the scenes](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/2622f839cafe16caaca28a445723699c3e7607b3/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKWebView.mm#L1413-L1428). Maybe with luck you can serialise and restore that over app launches?

Comment: Good point. Thank you. I targeting on iOS 11 and above. I decided to write my own navigation.

Comment: This works! I store it as Data upon url changes and restore it upon web view creation.